# Transparent Cloth Shader

Tags: shaders, transparency, lighting

I hope u can help me out, I want to make a Ghost with this shader.
Would be nice if someone can help[image]

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? How to make transparent cloth? How to make a ghost? There isn't a "Transparent Cloth" shader. Do you need to know how to make one? Please be clear when asking questions so we can better help you out. Giving a material transparency is just a matter of setting your "Transmission" levels in your principled shader, and plugging a "Volume Scatter" shader into the volume port of your material output. Again, the more detailed questions you ask, the better answers you will get.

Comment: I want to know how I can make this kind of shader?